# Use subfolders in training set to retrain Inception's Final Layer

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

In the example doc to [retrain Inception's Final Layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining#training_on_your_own_categories) the training image data is stored in folders. Each folder defines the category for the containing images through its name.

In the following example `rose-1.jpg` belongs to the category `roses` and `daisy-1.jpg` to the category `daisy`:

```
roses -> rose-1.jpg   
daisy -> daisy-1.jpg
```

Can I achieve higher granularity through subfolders? For example:

```
roses -> alba -> rose-alba-1.jpg
roses -> damascena -> rose-damascena-1.jpg
roses -> damascena -> rose-damascena-2.jpg
```

The doc is not clear about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately you can't create sub-classes like that. Instead, you can try naming your classes like this:

```
roses_alba -> rose-alba-1.jpg
roses_damascena -> rose-damascena-1.jpg
roses_damascena -> rose-damascena-2.jpg
```

I'd need to know more about what your requirements are though to understand if that meets your needs.